# Page-range indexing breaks using hyperref and imakeidx with xindy

Tags: hyperref, indexing, imakeidx, xindy, bugs

Loading `hyperref` together with `imakeindex` (using the latter's `xindy` option) seems to disable use of `\index` to index ranges of pages with `\index{keyword|(}`…`\index{keyword|)}`.  The keyword appears in the index but with a blank page-range.

The problem disappears if `hyperref` is not used, or the `xindy` option is disabled.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex%[options=-M texindy]% -M ff-ranges -L english -C utf8]

\begin{document}

\index{single page}
\index{range of pages|(}
This is some text to which the index should refer.  
\index{range of pages|)}

\printindex
    
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]
[image]

`.idx` file:

```
\indexentry{single page|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{range of pages|(hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{range of pages|)}{1}
```

`.ind` file:

```
\begin{theindex}
  \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
  \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
      \par\textbf{#1}\par
      \nopagebreak
  }

  \lettergroup{R}
  \item range of pages, 

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{S}
  \item single page, \hyperpage{1}

\end{theindex}
```

How can I fix this?  I need to use both `hyperref` and `xindy`.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/586381/231952. If you load `hyperref` before `imakeidx` you get the page number but it is not clickable. Anyway I am not sure that this is a good practice since `hyperref`  must be loaded usually after the other packages

Comment: Thanks - inspired by that answer I downloaded a patched version of `xindy` from https://github.com/jspitz/xindy.ctan and installed it.  The installation seems to have worked, but the pages are still not appearing.  I note that the generated `.idx` file contains the lines `\indexentry{range of pages|(hyperpage}{1}` and `\indexentry{range of pages|)}{1}`, i.e. the formatting command `hyperpage` appears with the opening `(` but not the closing one.

Comment: On further investigation I think the problem lies with hyperref and not with the xindy bug linked in Ivan's comment.  If I manually edit the idx file to add `hyperpage` after the right parentheses, the index works file.